# Adding a recursive function to my bejewled game

Tags: python, function, recursion, turtle-graphics

I am working on an assignment for my python class, and we are working on adding a recursive function to a bejewled game. I am honestly kind of lost and don't know what to add next in my recursive function that isn't done.

```
import turtle
import random

turtle.setup(800,600)
window = turtle.Screen()

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed('fastest')


def drawDot(t, x, y, diameter, colorP):
    t.up()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.pencolor(colorP)
    t.dot(diameter)

def drawboard(t, x, y, diameter,board):
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            drawDot(t, x, y, diameter + 5, 'black')
            drawDot(t, x, y, diameter, board[i][j])
            x = x + 60      
        y = y - 50
        x = -300

def shuffleboard(t, x, y, diameter, line):
    for i in range(len(line)):
        for j in range(len(line[i])):
            drawDot(t, x, y, diameter + 5, 'black')
            drawDot(t, x, y, diameter, line[i][j])
            x = x + 60      
        y = y - 50
        x = -300

def randomColor():
    randomColor = ['ivory', 'snow', 'gold', 'sky blue', 'indian red', 'slate gray', 'orange']
    num = random.randint(0,6)
    color = randomColor[num]
    return color

def generateBoard():
    board = []
    for r in range(10):
        row = []
        for i in range(10):
            color = randomColor()
            row.append(color)
        board.append(row)

    return board

t1 = turtle.Turtle()
x = -300
y = 240
diameter = 20

letterX = -300
letterY = 260

for r in range(10):
    t1.penup()
    t1.goto(letterX, letterY)
    t1.write(chr(r+ord('A')), move = False, align = 'center', font = ('Arial', 24, "normal"))
    letterX += 60
letterX = -300
for r in range(10):
    t1.penup()
    t1.goto(letterX - 35, letterY - 40)
    t1.write(r + 1, move = False, align = "center", font = ('Arial', 24, "normal"))
    letterY -= 50
t1.hideturtle()

start = input('previous board? (Y/N) ')
if start == "N":
    aList=[]
    board = generateBoard()
    generateBoard()
    drawboard(t, x, y, 25, board)


if start== "Y":
    fileName = input('enter file name(.txt): ')
    input_file=(fileName, 'r')
    for i in input_file:
        aList.append(i)

coordinate = input("enter your coordinate: ")
letter= coordinate[0]
number=int(coordinate[1:])
number=number-1

if letter == 'A':
    letIndex = 0
if letter == 'B':
    letIndex = 1
if letter == 'C':
    letIndex = 2
if letter == 'D':
    letIndex = 3
if letter == 'E':
    letIndex = 4
if letter == 'F':
    letIndex = 5
if letter == 'G':
    letIndex = 6
if letter == 'H':
    letIndex = 7
if letter == 'I':
    letIndex = 8
if letter == 'J':
    letIndex = 9    
number = int(coordinate[1:])
number = number - 1
print(board[number][letIndex])
finalBoard = []
save = input("save current board? (Y/N) ")
if save == "Y":
    outputFileName = input("enter output file: ")
    output_file=open(outputFileName, "w")
    board = str(board)
    output_file.write(board)
    output_file.close()
while save == "N":
    coord = input("enter your coordinate: ")
    letter = coord[0]
    if letter == 'A':
        letIndex = 0
    if letter == 'B':
        letIndex = 1
    if letter == 'C':
        letIndex = 2
    if letter == 'D':
        letIndex = 3
    if letter == 'E':
        letIndex = 4
    if letter == 'F':
        letIndex = 5
    if letter == 'G':
        letIndex = 6
    if letter == 'H':
        letIndex = 7
    if letter == 'I':
        letIndex = 8
    if letter == 'J':
        letIndex = 9    
    number = int(coordinate[1:])
    number = number - 1
    print(board[number][letIndex])
    save = input('save and quit? (Y/N)')
    if save == 'Y':
        outputFileName = input('enter output file: ')
        output_file=open(outputFileName, 'w')
        for i in board:
            finalBoard.append(i)
        finalBoard = str(finalBoard)
        output_file.write(finalBoard)
        output_file.close()

checked = []
def recursive(coordinate, checked, board):
    let = coord[0]
    num = coord[1:]
    num1 = num-1
    intnum = int(num1)
    topnum = intnum-1
    bottomnum = intnum+1
    letindex = ord(let)-65
    rightlet = letindex+1
    leftlet = letindex-1
    newright = rightlet + 65
    newleft = leftlet + 65
    rightcharacter = chr(newright)
    leftcharacter = chr(newleft)
    topcoord = let+str(topnum)
    bottomcoord = let+str(bottomnum)
    leftcoord = leftcharacter+num
    rightcoord = rightcharacter+num
    topcolor = board[topnum][letindex]
    bottomcolor = board[bottomnum][letindex]
    leftcolor = board[intnum][leftlet]
    rightcolor = board[intnum][rightlet]
    coordcolor = board[intnum][letindex]
    print(topcoord)
    print(bottomcoord)
    print(leftcoord)
    print(rightcoord)
    print(topcolor)
    print(bottomcolor)
    print(leftcolor)
    print(rightcolor)
recursive(coordinate, checked, board)
```

Comment: Any chance you can narrow down your code into the relevant parts to what you want to do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

So far, you've created the basic data structures for your game as well as the underpinnings to load, save, generate and display the board.  But what you haven't added is the logic by which a user's move is evaluated.  This is where a recursive function can be handy.

The recursive function you've written so far defines interesting things to look at to make a decision, but it neither makes decisions nor is recursive.  This function would typically be called after each user's input to decide what to do next in response to their move.

You might find some insight looking at other StackOverflow quesions relating to bejeweled game logic. For instance this one, on the [logic behind a bejeweled-like game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/logic-behind-a-bejeweled-like-game), although not in Python, discusses logic that may be similar to what you need and one of the responses is recursive.

If that doesn't help, try your own StackOverflow or Internet search.